# Selenium Wrapper not getting the correct html source page

Tags: ajax, vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a script to automate some actions. I'm opening a page with Selenium Wrapper (chrome) then wait 5 seconds (the page has some javascript/ajax, that changes the page), then I ask for the source code. I get the initial html not with the js and ajax changes (If I manually go to the navigator and right click -> source code I get the correct source code, though).

My VBA code is:

```
Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

selenium.Start "chrome", "http://about:blank"
selenium.setTimeout ("120000")
selenium.setImplicitWait (5000)
intRowPosition = 2
selenium.Open "http://www.somepage.com/%3Fstart%3D1"
selenium.sleep ("5000")

msgbox(selenium.getHtmlSource)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for getPageSource, explicitly states that

> If the page has been modified after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that the returned text is that of the modified page.

However it could also be due to synchronization issue. I am not familiar with VBA framework, so I don't know if it has an equivalent of [explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits), but if it does, it's better to wait for a particular condition that occurs only when the page fully loads ("with the js and ajax changes" as you expect) instead of "sleep" which does not guarantee that page is ready by the end of the wait.

Comment: I do not think is a wait issue, as I'm having the same problem when I debug and wait looong time until do the last instruction

Comment: @MarcoMartin it's quite easy to implement the code you shared on one of the "official" drivers, i.e. csharp driver. So if the issue on the page cannot be replicated with other driver,  it is probably a driver implementation at fault, in which case you would either have to report it to that driver's developer(s) or switch to another driver

Answer (score 0):

SeleniumWrapper is deprecated and no longer supported.
It has been replaced by SeleniumBasic:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

To get the source of a page:

```
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org"

MsgBox driver.PageSource
MsgBox driver.ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.innerHTML")
MsgBox driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML")
```